# SmtpClient, send email through smtp.gmail.com, but From another account

Tags: smtp, smtpclient

I wonna send email through gmail smtp, but users should see my corporative "From"

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("igor@dynback.com", "pass", "mail.dynback.com");
```

I am getting SmtpException:
"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required"

I heard its all possible and called "Relay", but I am not sure, do i need to put somehow google credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Save As" feature in gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a Google account for the credentials.  You should be able to set the From or ReplyTo address in your MailMessage to whatever you want.

Comment: Its sending, but i see no igor@dynback.com in From. Looks like found a solution: http://blog.abettergeek.com/server-management/windows-server-2008-r2-smtp-and-gmail-for-domains-or-how-i-learned-to-let-go-and-love-smart-hosts/